# RabbitMQ export vhost config

Tags: rabbitmq, export, vhosts, rabbitmqadmin

I'm running RMQ 3.83 (Erlang 22.3.1), and I am looking to export a single vhost only, with all it's relevant config (exchanges/queues/users) and then import it into our dev environment after changing a few values.

Is there a way I can do that with rabbitmqadmin, was looking around and have only found articles relating to a full RMQ config/definition export, which is not what I am aiming to do.

would this command do?:

rabbitmqadmin export -V vhost vhost.json

About the environment:

The RMQ app is running on an Ubuntu 20.4 three node cluster.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that command will get the list of exchanges, queues, and bindings for the specified vhost.

This will effectively call the http api endpoint api/definitions/vhost?download=vhost.json